# How to get a random number in a special section

Tags: random

I want to make a program which makes random chars. For that I plan to use ASCII (pick an int and convert it to char). But I have the problem that I cannot configure the range of the random numbers exactly...

This is my try:

```
value[a] = random.Next(48,57 || 65,90 && 97,122);
```

Can somebody help me with that? I'm new to programming, so sorry for that maybe stupid and easy question, but I really want to learn it.

Comment: Why not make an array of characters you want to choose from, then get a random number between 0 and size-1 to select into that array (you can even just use a static string instead of an array)? I think this will make your life much easier.

Comment: Boolean operators don't work like that. As @lc. says, you need a different approach

Comment: What language are we using here?

Answer (score 0):

```
string charString = "";
for(int k = 0; k < CountCharNeeded; k++)
{
    Random random = new rand();
    int rand = random.ne,26);
    int i =0;
    for(char a = 'a'; a < 'z'; a++)
    {
        if (i == rand)
        {
            // you get this no
            charString += a.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Overly complex O(n^2) solution that uses a fixed character set that does not include all of ASCII.  This can be done in O(n) where n is the number of characters to choose.